# Opening a new tab for sending an email

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm making a personal page as a website using react, and one of the "features" I wanted was a little portion that has contact information. I found a nice css file I liked that had space for four pieces of contact info and I thought of adding phone number, email address, linked in, and discord. I've done that for three of the four, but for sending an email, I have had issues with getting it to open in another tab.

I tried

```
<a href="mailto:your-email@example.com" target="_blank">
     <button className="card2">
          <FontAwesomeIcon className={'email'} icon={faEnvelope} size={'2x'}/>
     </button>
</a>
```

and thought it would open a new tab with my default mail client (for me gmail) to send an email to that example email, and on my phone hopefully it would go to the apply mail app.

Comment: I tried looking for how this is done in other places, and clicked on the email button on the "Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Twitter, or Facebook." that showed up with my question on stack overflow, and nothing happened there either. Is something supposed to happen?

Comment: Why do you nest a button inside a link? That seems redundant (and a potential source of problems)

Comment: @knittl sorry I am not very experienced, should I be using it as an onlick instead?
I tried this 
                <button className="card2">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon className={'email'} icon={faEnvelope} size={'2x'}
                                     onClick={() => {window.open("mailto:your-email@example.com", '_blank')}}/>
                </button>

instead but it just opened a new tab that has the mailto thing, in the URL bar not a mail client

Comment: Why do you need it to open in a new tab? for most it would just open up their email app anyways without `_blank`

Comment: That's what I figured too, but for some reason on my computer when I clicked it nothing happened, which I found quite odd? I deleted the _blank to no avail :(

Comment: @Kishan the button is likely eating the click event. Either use a link or a button, but not a button inside a link.

Comment: @knittl I changed it to a button
<button className="card2">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon className={'email'} icon={faEnvelope} size={'2x'}
                                     onClick={() => {window.open("mailto:your-email@example.com")}}/>
                </button>
but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Kishan Try a link. I don't know how React will handle/render those click handlers. A link can work without JavaScript (but well, since this is a React page, you already require JS)